# Zepto's clone() function not working properly or not possible to use clone() in combination with find()?

Tags: javascript, clone, zepto

I have a simple image-slider, the html looks like this:

```
<ul id="gallery-slider">
    <li class="slide-li" >
        <img src="img1.png" width="1024" height="590" alt="img1">
    </li>
    <li class="slide-li" >
        <img src="img2.png" width="1024" height="590" alt="img2">
    </li>
    <li class="slide-li" >
        <img src="img3.png" width="1024" height="590" alt="img3">
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Now I want to add some thumbs to it to have an overview of the images. I want to create the thumbs from the images in the slides. I am using Zepto and tried the following to get the images and create new ones:

```
//imageSlider is the image slider instance in use

for (var i = 1; i <= imageSlider.length; i++) {
    //find the image in li
    var img = $('#gallery-slider li').eq(i-1).find('img').clone().attr({'width': 268, 'height': 172});
        //view cloned element in console
        console.log(img);
    ...
    //here the img var will get pushed into an array
}
```

Now when you spit out the img var in the console, it shows empty objects. I think the problem is the find() function, because when I do this:

```
var img = $('#gallery-slider li').eq(i-1).clone();
```

the img var is not empty – the console output shows the cloned li elements. Is this a bug or can I not use the clone() function in combination with find() ?

**Edit:**

I also tried this:

```
var img = $('#gallery-slider li').eq(i-1).find('img'),
    thumb = img.clone();
```

– same result.

Comment: I tried, it worked fine. http://jsfiddle.net/HWY5u/

Comment: hmm, i tested it, works in firefox, but not in safari (actually doing this in safari). Does it work in safari for you? Maybe this is a browser issue after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the discussion before, in chrome and firefox it works fine, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HWY5u/).

And then I tried it in safari. `console.log(img)` indeed printed empty. But then I tried `console.log(img.length)`, it printed `1`.

So I think there maybe **some bug in safari's debug tools**.

Then I ignored the result of `console.log()` and try to use the cloned element with the following code:

```
$('#gallery-slider').after(img);
```

to see whether it is really empty or not.

And the result proved my opinion. It worked fine.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HWY5u/1/).

Answer (score 0):

<s>Zepto does not have a clone function. For reference, You can use [this chart](http://jsrun.it/21f/mrCH).</s>

You could easily implement clone with something like:

```
    $.fn.clone = function(){
          var ret = $();
          this.each(function(){
               ret.push(this.cloneNode(true))
          });
        return ret;
    };
```

from [here](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/issues/247).

Comment: I just tried your clone function, unfortunately the result is exactly the same: it doesn't work in combination with find(). I will have a look at that find() function, it does seem to return some kind of object that isn't cloneable...